# Call to undefined function pg_connect() in php

Tags: postgresql

I don't know whats wrong with the code, I am getting the following error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() on line 2

This seems to be a very common error as I have seen many posts regarding this, but not even one answer helped me.

Please help me overcome this error .

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.setup.php

Comment: I edited php.ini and restarted MAMP, but no luck.